# Anylogic- Function not changing boolean variable

Tags: java, anylogic

In Anylogic I have a variable that increases and decreases when agents pass through certain blocks.

The first variable 'robot4count' is a double, when the double reaches a value above 5 I want another variable 'robot4free' to change to false, and return to true when below 5. I would also like the variable to constantly update

The function I have written so far :

```
    if(robot4count<5){
    robot4free=true;
    }
    else if(robot4count>5){
    robot4free=false;
    };
```

Unfortunately the variable robot4free does not change. The functions access is public, set to 'Just action (returns nothing), and I do not have any arguments set. The double 'robot4count' changes but the boolean 'robot4free' doesn't.

Is there a problem with my code, or have the properties been set incorrectly? Any help would be great, thanks. (NOTE: I am new to Anylogic and have little experience in java)

Comment: code looks fine, share how you call this function and when. You probably do not call it at the correct point. Best add screenshots. Also note that you do not account for the case where the value is 5 exactly!

Comment: Ah, there's the problem, how do I call a function?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured it out

Comment: Please share how so others can benefit from it in the future :)

Comment: ill create a simpler example and post soon

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have to point out that your code must first consider whether there is a **5**, which is missing from your code.
The second point, I hope you can show your calling process, if the counter does not increment or decrement, do you need to consider whether your method is **the same call**? Or maybe your code **has some threading issues** causing some count errors? Here is my test, I think it should be fine:

**Method**

```
class Method{
public boolean countInt(double robot4count){
    if (robot4count>=0&&robot4count<=5){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**TestCount**

```
@Slf4j
public class TestCount {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AtomicInteger countInt=new AtomicInteger(0);
    Method method = new Method();
    for (int i = 0; i <10 ; i++) {
        new Thread(()->{
            int now = countInt.incrementAndGet();
            if (method.countInt(now)) {
                log.debug("true:{}",now);
            }else {
                log.debug("false:{}",now);
            }
        },""+i).start();
    }


}
}
```

```html
<br/>
<div align=center><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnI0a.png"></div>
```

Hope my test can help you!

[image: the test result]

Answer (score 0):

For the function to be able to detect if *conveyor1* has 5 agents on it I added

```
robot4count++
```

to the 'On enter' Action of *convey1*, and

```
robot4count--
```

to the 'On exit' Action of *queue1*.

The function

```
if(robot4count<5){
robot4free=true;
}
else if(robot4count==5){
robot4free=false;
}
else if(robot4count>5){
robot4free=false;
};
```

then detects if the variable *robot4count* is five or over, if so it changes the boolean variable *robot4free* to false.

*selectOutput* has the condition robot4free and this means that it allows items through only when there are less than five agents on *conveyor1*

*function4* is called On enter to *delay* (which is set to 0.1 seconds) through

```
function4()
```

[image: The top conveyor only allows 5 agents at a time.]

I hope this helps anyone who had the same questions as me.